# Flutter web not opening in Edge, but opening on chrome browser

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

We were about to launch our website today, https://www.vyapardost.com
When you click on Register on Free Button on this website, it redirects to our flutter web app.
But the Flutter web app not loading in Microsoft Edge, it's working in chrome.
Can someone guide me, please?

Today was the launch planned and we are stuck.

Comment: It's perfectly open in edges in my PC.

Comment: opening on safari too

Comment: Thanks all for letting me know, Almost Everyone is Able to open on Edge, But I think its a problem with edge on my Acer Swift 3 laptop only, tried clearing all catch and other browser data, windows updated to windows 11 latest version, don't know whats the issue, hope will automatically get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version you are testing on?
As per official documentation it is supported for Edge v1.2.0 and above. You can check for your target platforms if it is stably supported by Flutter on below link.

> Supported platforms/browsers: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/supported-platforms#supported-platforms

Comment: Windows 11 is updated, And Edge is Updated to Latest Version, Catch and Browser Data cleared. Laptop Acer Swift 3, Might be my machine problem.

Comment: Is this problem occurring on local machine while running the web-app in debug mode? OR you are testing a deployed version? 
Basically are you testing the app in debug mode on local OR in release mode from some server?